# Define MutableList of an object

Tags: android, kotlin

I have this block of code:

```
val page = object : AbstractViewRenderer(this, R.layout.pdf_page) {
    private var title: String? = null

    override fun initView(view: View) {}
}
```

Now I want to make a mutable list of `object : AbstractViewRenderer(this, R.layout.pdf_page)`.

I mean something like this:

```
val page[] : MutableList<object : AbstractViewRenderer> = ...
```

How to do it? What should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an [`object` expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions) creates a one-time, anonymous instance. If you want to reuse the logic inside it, create a class for it, something like this:

```
class MyViewRenderer(ctx: Context, layoutResId: Int) : AbstractViewRenderer(ctx, layoutResId) {
    private var title: String? = null

    override fun initView(view: View) {}
}
```

Then you can create instances or lists of instances of that class:

```
val page = MyViewRenderer(this, R.layout.pdf_page)

val pages: MutableList<AbstractViewRenderer> = mutableListOf(
        MyViewRenderer(this, R.layout.pdf_page),
        MyViewRenderer(this, R.layout.pdf_page),
        MyViewRenderer(this, R.layout.pdf_page)
)
```